# Sum the values from the column name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to sum up the values from the column named NOMINAL_MAX and paste this value in the indicated place. My code below shows no error, however, nothing is happening either. Where did I go wrong

```
Dim rTable As Range
Dim rCol As Range
Dim rCriteria As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim NOMINAL_MAX as String 
With wbMe.Worksheets("pochodne")
Nominal_MAX = "NOMINAL_MAX"
       LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
       Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=Nominal_MAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
       If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
           wbMe.Sheets("pochodne").Range("X35").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rTable.Columns(1), Nominal_MAX, rTable.Columns(rCol.Column))
       Else
           SumCriteria = CVErr(xlErrValue)
       End If
```

Comment: You never actually assigned a value to the variable. Add: `NOMINAL_MAX = "NOMINAL_MAX"`

Comment: @Rory i edited my post, added your comments but now im getting 0 its not sum ,

Comment: Could you explain in detail how you expect the `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf` to work? Are you perhaps looking to use `.Range("X35").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column))` instead in the `If` ?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber it's working now !! :) thanks for help

Comment: If you're getting 0, then either nothing matches your criteria, or the values add up to 0, or they are text.